# Light / Mesh inconsistency in one area - Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light

I'm trying to understand what's wrong with the lights in my scene.

I've made some kind of sci-fi corridor, inspired by the interior of an aircraft cabin.

The main mesh is first mirrored and then replicated with an array (blend file attached).

I'm struggling to correctly light the scene, I would like all the light sources to come from emitter materials properly assigned to the mesh itself. The overall result is not how I'd expect it. I have lots of light sources, filmic enabled, but very poor detail with 512 or even 1024 samples. The bad result is even more evident if I throw in a character made with Manuel Bastioni Lab: I can barely see the skin, is very dark like there's not enough light, but at least to my eyes there's even too much light in the scene overall.

[image: Very poor detail at 512 samples]

Then I noticed a strange behavior: the light on the floor near the bottom of the front wall (green box highlight). I really don't understand why the light is distributed in such a way in that portion. Moreover, hiding the wall doesn't change the result, and if I render the opposite side everything's ok.

[image: Weird light distribution]

Is there anything evidently wrong with how I'm distributing the lights? Or something's wrong with the mesh? The materials are those from Poliigon and worked pretty well in other cases.

By no means I'm aiming to photorealism: I'm just learning, trying to model and correctly distribute lights. Once I'm done, I'll try to export everything to UE4 and recreate the materials to achieve roughly the same outcome (I know UE4 isn't raytracing, but I'd like to use a few cycles rendering as "artwork references").

Here's a low quality version of the Poliigon carpet texture I'm using:
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: There seem to be lots of textures in your materials which are absent from the download and can't be diagnosed. Your materials appear to be mostly plain white, not sure what all those textures are actually doing there, but I'm gonna blindly guess they may be influencing your normals and altering the expected results

Comment: If you look at the normal map output in `FabricCarpetFine001_4K` I can see the pattern, however the .blend doesn't have the normal map so I'm not sure if that's the case for you too.

Comment: I'm not sure I can pack them, those are payed textures. I'll try to make low versions to show here.